# Google chart tooltip flashes on hover, how do you fix it?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

When I hover over a Google Chart tooltip, it keeps flashing, there seems to be some sort of bug there. I have tried it in different browsers and had other people test it too, all with the same result. I am sure you can try it too at https://developers.google.com/chart, just put the cursor over the pie chart, then place it over a tooltip and you will see what I mean.

Is there something that can be done to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "you" don't fix it.  Google does.  I suggest offering them feedback about their chart.

Answer (score 3):

**Cause of the flashing**

The tool tip only flashes if the mouse pointer is on top of the tool tip displayed:

1. mouseover an element brings up the tool tip
2. the mouse is over the tooltip
3. the element gets a mouseout event
4. the element hides the tool tip
5. the mouse is over the element
6. repeat from 1.

You could document it as a feature, notify Google, see if you can find the CSS class of the tool tip and add a `pointer-events: none;` rule (see below), or find the code that brings up the tooltip and change it from responding to `mouseover` and to responding to `mouseenter` (untested).

**Stopping the flashing**

Turning off pointer events on tooltip elements stops the flashes from occurring. For example by adding a style element at the bottom of the head section like

```
<style>
    .google-visualization-tooltip { pointer-events: none; }
</style>
```

**Warning**

This is not guaranteed: the class name is not documented and Google could change the class name in different locales or for other reasons at any time (I used the console to find it). Despite being an admitted hack, it may prove useful until something else can be done to resolve the flashes.

Comment: still works nice for me, thanks!